# Precedence of & (address) vs -> (member access) for c struct?

Tags: c, struct, operator-precedence

I have a piece of (legacy) code I'm trying to understand; it looks like this:

```
void *a =  (uint32 *)&b->c.d;
```

My question:
What gets stored in a? Is it:

1. The pointer to d is stored to a?
2. typecast the "value" of d (uint32 *) and store in a?
3. Anything else?

I'm looking for operator precedence in C, and I cannot find documentation for this kind of precedence.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Thanks - so it looks like the address of d will get typecasted to (uint32 *) and stored in a.

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I think about it.

`->` and `.` are not really infix operators. Their right-hand side is not an expression: If `x.y` and `x->y` are valid, then so are `(x).y` and `(x)->y`, but you cannot write `x.(y)` or `x->(y)`. The right-hand side is always a plain identifier, not a general expression.

That's why I call `.` and `->` meta-postfix operators: For every identifier `foo`, `.foo` and `->foo` are postfix operators.

A general rule of operator precedence in C is that postfix operators have the highest precedence, followed by prefix operators, followed by infix operators.

Your expression,

```
(uint32 *)&b->c.d
```

has two prefix operators (`(uint32 *)` and `&`) and two postfix operators (`->c` and `.d`). (Casts (of the form `( TYPE ) EXPR`) are also prefix operators.) Since postfix beats prefix, we can parenthesize it as

```
(uint32 *)(&((b->c).d))
```

which is evaluated as follows:

1. Take the value of `b`, which must be a pointer to a struct or union.
2. Dereference it and get the `c` field, which must itself be a struct or union.
3. Get the `d` field.
4. Take its address.
5. Cast the address to `uint32 *`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the clarity I needed. :)

Comment: Detail: C calls `struct` as having  _members_, not _fields_.  Still a good answer.

Comment: Missing conversion: 6. `uint32 *` converted to `void*` 7. pointer then saved.

Comment: @chux Those steps are not part of the expression, which is what my answer is going over.

Comment: True the `void*` conversion is not part of the RHS of the expression, but the assignment is part of OP's "My question: What gets stored in a?"  A `uint32 *` is not stored in `a`, but a `void *`.  IAC, a minor point.

Comment: @melpomene  what is the difference in operations between a.b->c and a->b.c? Is it (a.b)->c and (a->b).c respectively?